# Limited resource available in spark cluster

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, apache-spark-sql

If I have a dataset with 10GB of size and there is only 10GB of resource(executors) available in the spark cluster then how would it process programmatically?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Note: 10GB is not "big data"... Most SQL Servers store far more than that

Comment: 10GB is small data.. you can easily run on your cluster...  but we need to note a few points here .....                                                                                                             if your job lineage graph is linear (no shuffle) then it is very simple your cluster is good enough to run your job .. if there is a shuffle by any chance then you need to make sure enough disk size is available on executor nodes that's it. please go ahead and read about spark architecture/tuning.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to assume that the memory available to Spark has to equal or exceed the size of your data. That is not the case. Spark will spill to disk as needed.

Furthermore, compression will shrink the memory footprint of your data.

Bottom line: Proceed without persisting the data (`.cache()`).